# How to add Actual Approver in Approval History in Report?

Tags: reporting, approval-process, approval-history

Can someone please tell me how can i add Actual Approver in Approval History Report ?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer of my own question

Add **Last Actor field**

thanks